# iterating over IEnumerable ViewData in controller mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to foreach loop over a ViewData["element"] in order to build an 
array

error reads cannot complitly convert object to string[]

```
        foreach(var p in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewData["element"] as Array)
        {
            string[] workbookIDsLinks = p;
        }
```

the vuiewdat is from

```
ViewData["element"] = names.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(e => e.Attributes["id"].Value);
```

any help would be awesome

Comment: what is the type of `ViewData["element"]`?

Comment: Are you sure you can cast your `ViewData["element"]` to `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: iv added on how the ViewData is being populated in a cast from XML nodes being automatically set to IEnumerable i think

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx):

> if an array is cast to the type Array, the result is an object, not an array

So, you've got an object reference, even though you explicitly asked for an `Array`!

Rather than store an `IEnumerable<string>` (or `IEnumerable<anything>`) in `ViewData`, just convert to an array or list before you store it, by adding `ToList()` on the end of your assignment. Then you can more easily deal with it on the other end.

In your case, I'm not sure of the type of `names`, so I'm not sure what you need to do to turn your results into a list of `string`.

Comment: its not just that. no matter if you cast `ViewData["element"]` to `(IEnumerable<string>)` or `Array`. i think the OP doesnt know how foreach works. it iterates over elements. so the element is `string` or `object` not `string[]`.

Comment: True, but it explains the specific error OP is getting :-)

Comment: in theory looks good but actually I get this one the var list Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.XmlNode,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `IEnumerable<string>` here as it can be lazily executed (you can do search for *Deferred execution* to learn more) and data source can be invalid at this point (DB connection closed, XML file closed, etc). Instead use `ToArray()` to materialize your colllection.
2. There is no point of doing `foreach` as element is already a collection of elements;

In your controller:

```
ViewData["element"] = names
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(e => e.Attributes["id"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

In your view:

```
var workbookIDsLinks = ViewData["element"] as string[];
```

Comment: I am not wanting to us this in my View I am wanting to iterate over this for another call, within the controller

Comment: Then you have to use `TempData` or `Session` instead as `ViewData` is not persisted across multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ViewData["element"] = sitenames
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(e.Attributes["id"].Value, e.Attributes["name"].Value));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.